# Is it possible to call sub-method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, methods

As an experiment, I am trying to build the following hierarchy of methods around `Number`:

```
                                     Number
                                       |
                                       |
                                      pad()
                                       /\
                                      /  \
                                     /    \
                                    /      \
                                 left()   right()
```

Precisely, I want `left()` and `right()` to be the sub-methods of pad() so that I am able to pad the number by making a call something like:

```
var i = 100;
i.pad().left();
```

Here's an experimental script that I was working on:

```
/* 
    Javascript to pad zero's to a number at the left or right.
*/
Number.prototype.pad = function()
{
    Number.prototype.pad.left = function(l)
    {
        if(typeof l=='undefined') 
            l = 0;
        p = this+'';
        var r = l - p.length; 
        while((r--)>0)
            p = '0'+p;
        return p;
    }
    Number.prototype.pad.right = function(l)
    {
        if(typeof l=='undefined') 
            l = 0;
        p = this+'';
        var r = l - p.length; 
        while((r--)>0)
            p = p+'0';
        return p;
    }
}
i = 646;
padded = i.pad.left(9); /* Possible calling format*/
alert(padded);
```

How is this possible in Javascript?

Comment: Why not just call it padLeft and padRight and have it on the same level as pad?

Comment: @Lloyd, This was just an experiment. There may also be other similar cases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues fixed:
1) calling pad() instead of just pad
2) Pad() returns object with member left and right.
3) Most importantly, 'this' will not work inside the new functions as they are not part of number. Extracting the number outside the function.
4) p was inadvertly becoming public (window.p). Put a var in front.

[See it working](http://jsbin.com/uredov/3/watch)

```
  Number.prototype.pad = function() {

    var number = this.valueOf();
    return {
      left: function(l)
      {
        console.log(this);
          if(typeof l=='undefined') 
              l = 0;
          var p = number + '';
          var r = l - p.length; 
          while((r--) > 0)
              p = '0'+ p;
          return p;
      },
      right: function(l)
      {
          if(typeof l=='undefined') 
              l = 0;
          var p = number + '';
          var r = l - p.length; 
          while((r--)>0)
              p = p+'0';
          return p;
      }
  }
}
i = 646;
padded = i.pad().left(9); /* Possible calling format*/
  alert(padded);
```

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: What is the purpose of second parameter 'n'?

Comment: Yep. Fixed. BTW, that helped in debugging:)

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: Can you please give example of how you want to differentiate l and n?

Comment: oops!!! n was meant for something else I wanted to do before posting this question. I forgot to remove it. Sorry!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Consider something simpler. You could just pass left and right as parameters to `pad`. For example:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function( l,r ) {

  l = l || 0; r = r || 0;

  var arr = [ this ], 
      i = 0, j = 0;

  for ( ; i < l; ++i ) arr.unshift(0);
  for ( ; j < r; ++j ) arr.push(0);

  return arr.join('');

};

console.log( (12).pad(2,0) ); //=> 0012
console.log( (12).pad(0,1) ); //=> 120
console.log( (12).pad(3,2) ); //=> 0001200
```

Here's a shorter more functional and terse piece of code that works as well:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function( l,r ) { 
  return this.toString()
    .replace( /\d+/, new Array( ++l ).join('0') +'$&'+
      new Array( ++r||0 ).join('0'));
}
```

Comment: Though I am very grateful for your answer, I am still obliged to mark @raghavv's answer as accepted because that deals more with the question's current context. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
Number.prototype.lpad = function( num ) {

    var padding = new Array( num + 1 ).join("0"),
    result = padding + this.toString( 10 );
    return result.slice( -num );
}

Number.prototype.rpad = function( num ) {

    var padding = new Array( num + 1 ).join("0"),
    result = this.toString( 10 ) + padding;
    return result.slice( 0, num );
}
```